# Signatures do not match even if using same debug.keystore file (Android and Unity)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, keystore

**Background:**

I have been tasked to migrate an existing Android game (made using Cocos2D) into Unity.

The developer of the original app has given me the "debug" apk of the original game and the "debug.keystore" file that was used to sign it.

According to him, the debug.keystore file doesn't require any password. But apparently, in Unity, it is not possible to leave the password field blank because it will complain.

So in Unity, I have added that debug.keystore file in Player > Publishing Settings and entered the default password "android". For the alias (andrioddebugkey), I also entered the default password "android". (Apparently these are the default values for debug.keystore files, after doing some research)

**The problem:**

When I try to simulate an app update by installing the new (Unity) apk to overwrite the old app, I get the INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE / "signatures do not match the previously installed version" error.

Why is this happening even if I am using the same debug.keystore file as the original apk?

I've already incremented the Version and Bundle Version Code to be sure but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the app you are trying to install is already installed. Uninstall it and try again.

Comment: Yes I know that would work, but I am trying to simulate an app update because I need to test if the saved data from the old app is successfully picked up by the new version of the app. So uninstalling would be missing the point.

Comment: It is not signed with the same keystore so you have to uninstall it first. I don't think there is any other way. After uninstall and install with your new keystore key, you can use the same key and test your update as you want.

Comment: As mentioned, I am using the same keystore file that the original app uses. So there's no reason for the signatures to be different.

Comment: If it says signatures are different then it is different my friend. Here is another way. Tell the owner of the keystore file to put a password to it(i guess you can put a password to a keystore file in android studio, 6 characters minimum) then give it to you. Then you can use the same key and use that password to sign it.

Comment: I'll look into it. Thanks for the help man.

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider marking my answer as correct.

Comment: hi 

i am facing same problem 
my friend gave me debug keystore file, he used on android studio 
I replaced my debug keystore file in my .android folder 

still i get INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package a signatures do not match previously installed version
when trying to update the app.